# "ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down" when using jest with mongoose

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mongoose, jestjs

i have two test files that connect with mongoose, the problem started when i added the second one
i tried to use `jest.useFakeTimers()` after imports but nothing changed

*here is the test file*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const supertest = require("supertest");
const app = require("../app");
const api = supertest(app);
const User = require("../models/user");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

describe("adding users", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await User.deleteMany({});

    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash("sekret", 10);
    const user = new User({ username: "root", passwordHash });

    await user.save();
  });
  test("adding users successfuly", async () => {
    const newUser = {
      name: "john oliver",
      username: "karana",
      password: "ooiiu",
    };
    await api.post("/api/users").send(newUser).expect(200);
  });
});

afterAll(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

*and here is the mongoose model*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    minlength: 3,
  },
  passwordHash: String,
});
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

userSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString();
    delete returnedObject._id;
    delete returnedObject.__v;
    delete returnedObject.passwordHash;
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

*here is the controller*

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const usersRouter = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/user");

usersRouter.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const users = await User.find({});
  res.json(users);
});

usersRouter.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const body = req.body;

  if (body.password.length >= 3) {
    const saltRounds = 10;
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, saltRounds);

    const user = new User({
      name: body.name,
      username: body.username,
      passwordHash,
    });

    try {
      const result = await user.save();
      res.status(200).json(result);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  } else {
    res
      .status(400)
      .json({ error: "password must be atleast 3 charecters long" });
  }
});

module.exports = usersRouter;
```

*and there router is * `app.use("/api/users", usersRouter);` as written in the `app.js` files.

***here is the error am getting***

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at BufferList.Readable (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:179:22)
      at BufferList.Duplex (node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
      at new BufferList (node_modules/bl/bl.js:33:16)
      at new MessageStream (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:35:21)
      at new Connection (node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:54:28)
C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:111
  var isDuplex = stream instanceof Duplex;
                        ^

TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
    at new ReadableState (C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:111:25)
    at BufferList.Readable (C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:183:25)
    at BufferList.Duplex (C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_duplex.js:67:12)
    at new BufferList (C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\bl\bl.js:33:16)
    at new MessageStream (C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:35:21)
    at new Connection (C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:54:28)
    at C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:36:29
    at callback (C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:280:5)
    at TLSSocket.connectHandler (C:\Users\oussama\Desktop\web-projects\fullstackopen-part4\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:325:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1530:10)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:710:12)
```

the error happen after saving the data (users) to mongoDB.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by using the [jest-mongodb](https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb) preset which supplies all the async config necessary for Jest to run smoothly with MongoDB.

Note that Mongoose doc [warns](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html) against using `jest.useFakeTimers()` because they "stub out global functions like `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`, which causes problems when an underlying library uses these functions"

Comment: Could you please share how you implemented jest-mongodb to solve this?